# How to be able to use .class from a getConstructor()? - Java

Tags: java, api, class, events, types

In java, I am working on a API for a software I am working on that will allow people to extend the software on their own. Right now, I am currently working one the event system, which is going just fine. I am trying to use .class to get the needed argument type so the function will run. Is there any code I can use to be able to get a variable from a constructor (A string for example that has the class directory) And then make it so I can use .class on it? I would love to know!

Note: if some of the variables or constructors don't look like they are from java, it's probably because they are part of the API I am working on.

Here is my code:

```
private void throwEvent() {
    PSLPE = new PocketServerListPingEvent(this, Packet.getAddress(), Packet.getPort(), ServerSettings.getPEMOTD());
    ArrayList<Class<?>> Listeners = PluginManager.getListeners();
    for(int i = 0; i < Listeners.size(); i++) {
        Method[] MethodList = Listeners.get(i).getMethods();
        for(int j = 0; j < MethodList.length; j++) {
            if(MethodList[j].isAnnotationPresent(EventHandler.class)) {
                if(MethodList[j].getParameters()[0].getType().equals(PocketServerListPingEvent.class)) {
                    try {
                        Class<?> EventClass = Class.forName(Listeners.get(i).getName());
                        Constructor<?>[] EventCtorList = EventClass.getConstructors();
                        for(int k = 0; k < EventCtorList.length; k++) {
                            Constructor<?> ctor = EventClass.getConstructor(Class.forName(EventClass.getConstructors()[k].getParameters()[0].getType().toString().substring(6)));
                            Object EventObject = ctor.newInstance(EventClass.getConstructors()[k].getParameters()[0].getType());
                            Method EventMethod = EventObject.getClass().getMethod(MethodList[j].getName(), PocketServerListPingEvent.class);
                            EventMethod.invoke(EventObject, PSLPE);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't understand what you're trying to ask here. Could you re-word the question maybe?

Comment: @immibis Just did, refresh :) Sorry about that!

Comment: I still can't tell what your question is, sorry. Maybe post what you think your code would look like if it was possible (obviously it won't be real code, but it might be close enough). Or maybe someone else knows what you're trying to do.

Comment: @immibis Ok, I try my best to word these questions. But you know how when you invoke a method? Like in the code with PocketServerListPingEvent.class? And you see where I have the getConstructor method? I want to be able to get a class from a string (The directory to it) and have .class at the end of it so it will get the constructor from the class and create a new instance of the class I want to load correctly. For example, I would have the string "net.codeguys.ChillyDogs" And I could use .class on it after using a function or something similar to cast it as a class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [`Class.forName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)).

It returns the `Class` object for the class with the given name, or throws an exception if there is no such class. For example:

```
Class<?> chillyDogsClass = Class.forName("net.codeguys.ChillyDogs");
```

or

```
String className = new Scanner(System.in).readLine();
try {
    Class<?> unknownClass = Class.forName(className);
    System.out.println("Successfully found " + unknownClass.toString());
} catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println(className+" doesn't exist!");
}
```

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to use .class on this method?

Comment: @SuperstarGamer-Trent what? It does the same thing `.class` does.

Comment: Ok, let me try that then.

Comment: I am getting a illegalargument exception

Comment: Let me see if I can see whats happening real quick.

Comment: Ok, it happens when I create a new instance with it. It gets the class fine, but creating a new instance (ctor.newInstance(chillyDogClass) will not work)

Comment: @SuperstarGamer-Trent and is `ctor` a reference to a constructor that takes a `Class` as an argument?

Comment: Yes it is, the class has a constructor that requires a class from it. Particulary the class I am loading. (Not Chillydogs, but another. Chillydogs was an example)

Comment: @SuperstarGamer-Trent well it sounds like your problem isn't related to the use of `Class.forName`, so it's a separate question.

Comment: Ok, well. you definitely helped me solve the first part! Thanks! :D